Equation for the deflection of a flexible wing due to bending moments with a non-negligible rate of deflection when a point load is applied to its end
Suppose I have a model wing made of some flexible (easily bendable) plastic, I want to find a function which can describe the amount of deflection as a function of the distance from the support of the wing due to the bending moments caused internally due to the point loading force at the end tip of the wing.
So far I have used the following relation; Source. (In my case, there is no bending moment parallel to the XZ plane, i.e., $M_y=0$)
$$\frac{E\cos(\alpha)}{R}=\frac{M_xI_{yy}}{I_{xx}I_{yy}-I_{xy}^2}\qquad(1)$$
Where $\alpha$ is the angle between the x-axis and the neutral axis.
I then also used the radius of curvature equation to get a second order differential equation;
$$\frac{|\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}|}{(1+(\frac{dy}{dz})^2)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{R}\qquad(2)$$
To get that the rate of deflection of the wing can be expressed as;
$$\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{pF_{||}z^2}{\sqrt{4E^2-p^2F_{||}^2z^4}}\qquad(3)$$
Where $F_{||}$ is the loading force and $p$ is just a constant;
$$p=\frac{I_{yy}}{\cos(\alpha)(I_{xx}I_{yy}-I_{xy}^2)}\qquad(4)$$
I am not including how I derived the above relation (Eq. 3) for the sake of brevity. Although, now I am at odds with the fact that I cannot seem to represent the deflection of the wing as any elementary function. Which becomes evident when I try asking wolframalpha.com to try an solve the differential equation.
Note that I could easily get a function for the deflection if I could just assume that the rate of deflection of the wing is negligible which makes $\frac{dy}{dz}≈0$ (As it done here with a beam). And then, I could use this approximation and procced from Eq. 2. Although, this approximation is only possible if the wing is stiff and not easily bendable.
My question is that since there is no "elementary" representation for the deflection, does there at least exist a closed form representation for it?

Ok, I finally figured it out.
If we represent the rate of deflection in the following form;
$$\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{\gamma z^2}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2z^4}}$$
Where;
$$\gamma=\frac{pF_{||}}{2E}=\frac{I_{yy}F_{||}}{2E\cos(\alpha)(I_{xx}I_{yy}-I_{xy}^2)}$$
Then using wolframalpha.com and some deduction and simplification from the form that wolframalpha.com gives, we can get that the Maclaurin series of the rate of deflection is just;
$$\frac{dy}{dz}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\gamma^{2i+1}4^{-i}\frac{(2i)!}{(i!)^2}z^{4i+2}$$
Hence we can easily solve the differential equation to get that;
$$y=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4i+3}\gamma^{2i+1}4^{-i}\frac{(2i)!}{(i!)^2}z^{4i+3}+C$$
And you can easily find $C$ using boundary conditions.
